# tmux link-window to remote window

Tags: tmux

In a server, there's a persistent `tmux` session, with several windows running 24/7.

At my local computer, I run several `tmux` sessions, one at a time, depending on the type of work.

I wonder if it's possible to `link-window -s "session:window at remote server" -t "local_session:local_window`

I'd just like to integrate one window of the remote session in my current local session.

Comment: This would be _very_ useful for keeping an uninterrupted session on a server while also multitasking locally, without having to run `tmux`es inside of `tmuxes` and dealing with those consequences. I've searched a bit, though, and there unfortunately doesn't seem to be any way to _do_ it. :(